# Visual PHPUnit Internal Error, Failed opening require 'PHP/CodeCoverage/Filter.php'

Tags: php, apache, phpunit, pear

I've tried using Visual PHPUnit. The installation instructions ([here](https://github.com/NSinopoli/VisualPHPUnit)) are rather inaccurate, but once the setup was done, I was getting a 500 Internal Error when bringing up the project's page in a browser.

Digging into the apache error logs gave me the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHP/CodeCoverage/Filter.php'

(include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/home/gabriel/Projets/Code/ActiMeeting/web/phpunit:/usr/bin/pear') 
in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 46
```

PHPUnit works very well, but fearing I was using an outdated version of either PEAR or PHPUnit, I spent an afternoon uninstalling/reinstalling them. Now I'm back to the start, PHPUnit - which had stopped working because it couldn't find PEAR - finally works again.

But I'm still getting this error. I have checked that the 'pear_path' in Visual PHPUnit's bootstrap.php file is the right one, but somehow, when called by Apache, PHPUnit suddenly loses PEAR.

How do I make sure that Apache can fire up PHPUnit with the right dependencies? I tried editing php.ini and positively defining PEAR's path, but without luck.

Comment: Do you remember the solution to this issue? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/bin/pear` is an executable file and not a directory in which pear files reside.

Fix that by using pear's `php_dir` in the include path. Get it on the command line with

```
pear config-get php_dir
```

Add that to the `include_path` in php.ini, and restart apache.

Comment: The output of `pear confing-get php-dir` is ̀`/usr/share/php`. I put it in the `include_path` in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`, restarted apache and got the following error:
 
̀`PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHP/CodeCoverage/Filter.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/var/www/VisualPHPUnit:/usr/share/php') in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 46`

Basically, even that doesn't find pear. I don't really think there's a fix...

Comment: Where is PHPUnit installed? Is it listed when running `pear list -c phpunit`?

Comment: It is listed under `pear list -c phpunit`, it is installed in `/usr/bin/phpunit`. PHPUnit on its own works fine, but when Visual PHPUnit tries to use it, it breaks.